# How do I add files to VS Solution Explorer with a wildcard in the project file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In my project file I include all of the .cpp and .h files in a directory by using a wildcard as shown in the code snippet below. Everything compiles just fine.

The annoying issue I run into is I have to add files to the Solution Explorer manually via the Add Existing Item dialog. If I don't use a wildcard and spell out every file, I don't have the same problem. Not something I want to do with a boatload of source files though.

Is there a way to get these wildcard includes into the Solution Explorer?

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ClCompile Include="$(SrcDir)\*.cpp" >
    <Link>%(FileName)</Link>
  </ClCompile>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <ClInclude Include="$(SrcDir)\*.h">
    <Link>%(RecursiveDir)\%(FileName)</Link>
  </ClInclude>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: In the Add Existing Item dialog, you can select multiple files. You can also type in your own globs. So in File name, enter `*.cpp;*.h` (add a semicolon and any other globs you want) and those files show up. Select them all and click Add. Doesn't work over multiple directories though.

Comment: I was hoping for something I could put in the project file. The project file is version controlled and it would be nice if the project file just worked for everyone that uses it.

Comment: Yeah, that's why it's a comment; I'm hoping someone can give you a real answer, not a workaround. I don't have any experience with C(?) projects, so I'm not going to be of much help if there are wrinkles there. Crossing my fingers!